# Using data agumentation for a frozen pre-trained model

Tags: transfer-learning, data-augmentation

I was following the following article with regards to doing transfer learning:

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

In the section, Using the bottleneck features of a pre-trained network: 90% accuracy in a minute, the authors mentioned that: `"Note that this prevents us from using data augmentation"`

I am not very clear about this; is there a rule that discourages the use of data augmentation when the pre-trained model is totally frozen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can definitely use data augmentation when the layers of the pre-trained model are frozen.

In this article, the author refers to the size of VGG16 which is [quite a large](https://keras.io/applications/#documentation-for-individual-models) CNN. Also, he trains the model on his CPU which slows down training even more. Therefore, he does not want to use data augmentation, as that would increase the training time even more:

> Running VGG16 is expensive, especially if you're working on CPU, and we want to only do it once. Note that this prevents us from using data augmentation.